# Autonomous homonculi vs mass-produced homonculi, which one would be more restricted by the Geneva Convention?

Tags: science-based, warfare, politics, ethics

I needed monsters for my story, but with each added "quirk", dragons became more and more like overgrown, but well-behaved, flying housecats with scales. And I also didn't want them to be "monsters", just cool non-human characters.

Taking a page out of Shingeki no Kyojin and Full Metal Alchemist, I settled with deformed humans with little autonomy, controlled by a single person.

Homonculi are genetically altered, artificial humans, i.e: they don't have parents, only a designer.

**Mass-produced homonculi** are optimized for Zerg Rush tactics. They can hibernate, have no sense of fear, and can be programed by their coordinate to execute various tasks.

In terms of capability, they are about as good at combat (aiming, carrying stuff, etc...) as, your average draftee. Their biggest strength is their increased resilience to gunshot wounds, such as fast-clotting blood.

**Autonomous homonculi** are supersoldiers, playing the nieche of special forces and commanders on the battlefield. They have human intelligence and complete autonomy, their loyalty and skills are thus the result of years of training. They're also biologically immortal and capable of perfect regeneration.

They usually have around 20-50 mass-produced homonculi under their command. As per law, they have unnatural hair and eyecolors to help discern them from regular humans, expect to see lots of aquamarine, blue and purple hair.

---

Storywise, Captain McKenna, an autonom homonculus with aquamarine hair and scarily laid-back personality, is supposed to be a more serious breach of "International Law" than mass-produced homonculi.

Now, my International Law was meant to be an extrapolation of the "spirit" of the Geneva Convention to cover new weaponry like homonculi, mindless titans, experimental internet gas, and televangelists.

However, I'm unsure if Captain McKenna would be a more dangerous weapon than the squads of mindless homonculi he controls, though non-homonculi can also be coordinates.

**Based on the principles of the Geneva Suggestion, which homonculi type would be the more dangerous?** Assume a near-future Earth as our setting, and also that most of Europe, Russia, Asia, and North America has the capability to create and stockpile homonculi.

I mean, autonomous homonculi are effectively slave warriors, while mass-produced homonculi only feel recoil when pulling the trigger, and if the coordinate is employed by a PMC...

Comment: Why try to shoehorn this restriction into the Geneva Conventions where it doesn't properly belong? Nations can always get together and pass a new law just for you if they think you're up to something, like assembling a clone army.

Comment: What are the parameters of the homunculi. Based on your description I would be less worried about homunculi being banned for being a weapon and moreso being banned because they are a sentient species created to be slaves to humans. Of course, today [major corporations openly admit to enslaving other human beings while daring the UN to do something about it](https://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/2016/feb/01/nestle-slavery-thailand-fighting-child-labour-lawsuit-ivory-coast)

Comment: @user2352714 That's a concern with autonomous ones. Mass-produced homonculi are about as human as your average image-upscaling AI on github.

Comment: @Mephistopheles The question would be if other people know it. Your average person would be a lot more likely to ascribe sapience to a non-sapient humanoid than a sapient but non-humanoid A.I. Either way the first thing you have to worry about is people decrying the use of homunculi because it's essentially industrialized slavery.

Comment: why not both? also what happen if pure blood human dye their hair? is it restricted to have that color or they dont have hair dye?

Answer (score 3):

**Geneva conventions cover GAS & MINES.
WHY?
Because they won't recognize Enemy forces and will hurt Non-Combatants as well.**

If your Mass-produced crap will shoot everything that moves, it will shoot a mother hugging a babe.

Your High-End operatives, custom-crafted cream, will be able to discern when it is unlawful to do harm and only engage Soldiers.